# vim getting rid of special character ^I 

Tags: vim, plugins, dotfiles

I have installed some ***[dot files](https://github.com/sontek/dotfiles/)*** in vim. The files that I edit now works fine but some file which I don't own sometimes display special characters as below.

```
39 struct {^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I\
40 ^Istruct type *tqe_next;^I/* next element */^I^I^I\
41 ^Istruct type **tqe_prev;^I/* address of previous next element */^I\
42 }
```

How can I fix this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^I` is `tab`.

Use the below to not display it.

```
:set nolist
```